# Alguien sabe porque me sucede este error y como puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datatables

Ejecuto mi código para mostrar estos datos de MySQL en Datatables y me sale este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi Script

```
var columns = [];
function getDT() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "consulta_table.php",
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        columnNames = Object.keys(data[0]);
        for (var i in columnNames) {
          columns.push({data: columnNames[i], 
                    title: capitalizeFirstLetter(columnNames[i])});
        }
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            ajax: "consulta_table.php",
            columns: columns
        } );
      }
    });
}

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  
  getDT();

  
} );
```

Y este es mi código PHP

```
<?php 
include_once 'database.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();   


$query = "SELECT * FROM vista_envio";
$stmt = $conexion->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print json_encode($data);//envio el array final el formato json a AJAX
$conexion=null;
?>
```

Cuando miro el Datatable me muestra los nombres de las columnas correctamente, pero los datos pertenecientes a ellas no, se queda en cargando y me sale ese error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ACTUALIZACION: Al parecer al lado de la columna me salen las posiciones de cada columnas y despues si me salen sus nombres y por eso me sucede ese error, como puedo solucionar eso, que me salgan solo los nombres?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el código del data table?

Comment: Por el mensaje de rror creo que es un error javascript, puede ser algo tan simple como un id o clase de un bloque mal escrito. Yo abriría el debugger en el navegador y pondría un Break en la línea donde dice el error (la 61) a ver que pasa con la variable que da error .

Comment: @Jacobo el Script esta arriba en la publicación

Comment: @Juan Amigo hice una actualización a la publicación, porque al parecer salen mas columnas y es porque parecer ser que se pintan las posiciones de cada nombre pero no estoy muy seguro.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: @jhonny cuando usas datatables y quieres ayuda ... te recomiendo que incluyas todo si te piden el html inclúyelo; muchas veces el problema esta en el html, tan simple puede ser tu error como preguntarte la tabla que esta usando `#example`  Existe en el html, si no existe es normal que te salga ese error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya logre solucionar el error, con  `console.log(typeof data);` revise primero que data es el que me llegaba, después en esta linea de código.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax: "consulta_table.php",
        columns: columns
    } );
```

Quite esta linea de codigo `ajax: "consulta_table.php",` y puse `data` puesto que ya recibía los datos por la primera URL de AJAX.
Adjunto el código corregido.

```
<script>

       var columns = [];

            function getDT() {
                $.ajax({
                  url: "index2.php",
                  success: function (data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    columnNames = Object.keys(data[0]);
                    for (var i in columnNames) {
                      columns.push({data: columnNames[i], 
                                title: capitalizeFirstLetter(columnNames[i])});
                    }
                    $('#example').DataTable( {
                        data: data,
                        columns: columns
                    } );
                  }
                });
            }

            function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
                return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
              
              
              getDT();

              
            } );

</script>
```